# Programmatically log a user in

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using Node/Express and Passport for user authentication.

In some cases, a user can provide a token to login instead of a username/password.

I'd like to log them in programmatically when they hit the endpoint. I'd ideally like to do something like this:

```
app.post('/tokenlogin', function(req, res) {
    User.find({ token: req.body.token }, function(err, result) {
        if (result) {
            result.logIn();
            res.json({ success: true, user: result });
        }
    });
});
```

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: Looks correct. Make sure to set the whatever flag you need and redirect after POSTing:  `if (result) { req.session.user = result; res.redirect('/'); }`

Comment: Is the correct syntax req.session.user? Or just req.user?

Comment: I actually missed the Passport part. You have to use passport to log in. Let me look this up...

Comment: Pretty vanilla Passport stuff. Usually I access the authenticated user in a request via `req.user`.